# Number of distinct column A group by B

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table containing the following data.

```
SELECT *
FROM temp_table LIMIT 5

id  trip_id segment_id  session_id  start_timestamp     lat_start   lon_start   lat_end     lon_end travelmode
563097015   563097  15  128618  2017-05-20 17:47:12+01  41.1783308  -8.5949878  41.1784478  -8.5948463  0
563097013   563097  13  128618  2017-05-20 17:45:29+01  41.1781344  -8.5951169  41.1782919  -8.5950689  0
563097011   563097  11  128618  2017-05-20 17:43:41+01  41.1781196  -8.5954075  41.1782139  -8.5950689  0
563097009   563097  9   128618  2017-05-20 17:41:48+01  41.1782497  -8.595197   41.1781101  -8.5954124  0
563097003   563097  3   128618  2017-05-20 17:10:29+01  41.1832512  -8.6081606  41.1782561  -8.5950259  0
```

And I know that I have 5 distinct value of `travelmode`.  So I want to count number of segments (`segment_id`) by distinct `travelmode`.

That's how many segments are `0` as `travelmode`; how many have `1` as `travelmode` etc

**EDIT**

Required output:

```
travelmode  segments
0   273
1   143
2   198
3   236
4   120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use DISTINCT keyword inside your `count` function:

```
SELECT travelmode, COUNT(DISTINCT segment_id) NumOfSegments
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY travelmode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
Select Distinct travelmode, Count(*) as Count 
from tempTable 
Group By travelMode
```

Comment: No need for `distinct` as `group by` will do the job

Comment: hold on please, I want to count unique segments by travel mode, as in the question edit.

Comment: @Shmiel does this address the required output as in the question edit? Since for example the sample given in the question is only `1 segment`  of `0 travelmode`.

Comment: @super_ask this answer (without `distinct`) will `count` all rows `group by` travelmode which means it will return number of rows per travelmode.

Comment: @Shmiel because the data is logged at interval of about 3 seconds, so each unique `segment` consists of bunch of number of rows, depending on its duration. For example in the question, it is all about `segment 563097`  done by `travelmode 0`.